# Integrating cos(z^2) over the a circle from pi/4 to 5pi/4

Tags: complex-analysis

Trying to integrate cos(z^2) over the circle of radius 1, centered at origin, from the portions bounded by (1+i) to (-1-i). My work is below. I am lost. I want to apply Cauchy's Integral Formula but am unsure how. I mean there's no poles.

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\int_{\gamma} \cos \left(z^{2}\right) d z \\
\theta_{1}=\frac{\pi}{4}, \theta_{2}=\frac{5 \pi}{4} \\
\gamma(t)=\cos (t)+i \sin (t) \\
\gamma^{\prime}(t)=-\sin (t)+i \cos (t) \\
\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5 p i}{4}} \cos \left(\cos ^{2}(t)+2 i * \cos (t) \sin (t)-\sin ^{2}(t)\right) *(-\sin (t)+i * \cos (t)) d t
\end{array}
$$

Comment: hint: maybe the residue theorem might help?

Comment: Im looking into it. I'm having difficulty understanding how to calculate it.

Comment: So, is it valid to say that since the function has no poles, its residue is zero, and if its residue is zero then the integral of it over gamma is zero. ?

Comment: yes, indeed it is.